# Getting this window scroll trigger to work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this scrip that is designed to show an alert when you go all the way to the bottom of the page. This works on major big browsers but it does not work on Internet explorer so how can I get this to work on Internet Explorer?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
         alert("End of page");
     }
}

});
```

```css
h1{
background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>z</h1>
```

Comment: So what are you getting in IE instead? What does the console say? Also waht IE are you referring to? 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 or 11?

Comment: It's strange it shows no errors in the console that's what throws me off. xp

Comment: It does not say anything and I am on IE 11

Comment: Go to the console and simply paste `window.innerHeight`, `window.scrollY`, and `document.body.scrollHeight` an see if all exist.

Comment: It is showing in the DOM Explorer when I go to the script tag section it does show the JS code.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: I navigate to the console and it does not let me past anything so I don't know what you mean by your statements

Comment: The area in IE 11 where you can paste is only one line, right below the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on IE trust me.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
         alert("End of page");
    }
}

});
```

```css
h1{
background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>a</h1>
<h1>z</h1>
```